# Why does Settings | About say "Mesa Intel" instead of "Nvidia" when using Wayland?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, wayland

The Graphics section of the **Settings | About** page under Wayland in Ubuntu 20.04 is confusing me.

It claims that I am using **Intel** graphics, while all other system information indicates that I am using **Nvidia** graphics.

When I log into a Wayland session, the Graphics section states:

> Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphic...

However, when I log into an XOrg session, the Graphics section states:

> NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] / Mesa Intel® UHD Gra...

Under both Wayland and XOrg sessions, the Software & Updates app consistently shows:

> Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-455 (proprietary, tested)

Is it normal for Ubuntu in Wayland to not list NVIDIA on the Settings | About page?

Or am I over looking something?

---

To ensure Nvidia would be active in Wayland, I took the following steps:

1. Installed the Nvidia drivers using:

   ```
    ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu autoinstall nvidia
   ```
2. Enabled Wayland option on GDM in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

   ```
    grep "WaylandEnable" /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
    WaylandEnable=true
   ```
3. Removed the rule disabling Wayland on GDM with Nvidia in `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules`.

   ```
    grep "DRIVER" /lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules
    # DRIVER=="nvidia", RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-disable-wayland"
   ```
4. Blacklisted Nouveau in Grub in `/etc/default/grub`.

   ```
    grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=nouveau"
   ```

---

Here is the output of various commands showing graphics information, if they help.

```
sudo lshw -C display

  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:151 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:153 memory:dc000000-dcffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:dd000000-dd07ffff
```

...

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
    Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP108M [GeForce MX150]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

...

```
lsmod | grep nvidia

nvidia_uvm           1007616  0
nvidia_drm             53248  0
nvidia_modeset       1216512  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              27701248  20 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   491520  9 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

...

```
nvidia-smi

Tue Dec 29 22:43:33 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.38       Driver Version: 455.38       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

...

```
sudo prime-select query

on-demand
```

Comment: Pretty certain the nvidia proprietary blob doesn't work with Wayland yet