# Why is the window manager showing faded things after they're removed?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, window-manager

I upgraded from bionic to focal today. Since then whenever a visual element is dismissed, it hangs around in slightly transparent form until the next event. This even applies to text in the terminal!

I apologize for taking a photo of the screen, but taking a screenshot is one of the actions which removes the ghost images.

[image]

This is the effect of switching away from `top` in `screen` to a new screen.

This isn't stopping me working; it's just weird. I'd like it to stop. I'm running a pretty standard GNOME Ubuntu desktop, with gnome-shell as the window manager.

Comment: Are you using Wayland? Do you have Nvidia graphics?

Comment: Perhaps check and experiment with your preferences in the terminal. It looks like an issue with transparency to me.

Comment: *taking a screenshot is one of the actions which removes the ghosts* - this suggests to me that the problem has to do with your display hardware, and not anything in the software or OS.

Comment: @PJSingh yes, Wayland. How do I find out whether I have Nvidia graphics?

Comment: @vanadium it's not just in the terminal, though-- it's system menus and everything.

Comment: @Nmath fair enough, but then why would the problem appear only on a dist-upgrade?

Comment: You can check in System Settings | About | Graphics. It will say "NVIDIA" if it is being used. Try switching to a different session (Wayland or Xorg) on the GDM login screen, and see if you still have this issue. Not sure if this is your issue, but it would be a quick easy test to eliminate one possibility. Also note, if you pick "Wayland", NVIDIA is *not* used, even if you have the proprietary drivers installed (per the comment on this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303794/why-does-settings-about-say-mesa-intel-instead-of-nvidia-when-using-waylan).

Comment: @PJSingh thanks: "Graphics" says llvmpipe. I'll switch to a different session now and see whether that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, but I'm not sure which of the suggestions above resolved it! I suspect [`aptitude` had resolved broken package dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164587/how-can-you-unhold-remove-a-hold-on-a-package) which hadn't shown up until I rebooted.

All happy now. Thank you, lovely people.